# How to send an event for specific socket connection with ratchet

Tags: php, sockets, ratchet, reactphp

First see this piece of code:

```
use Ratchet\Resource\ConnectionInterface;

class MyApp {
protected $connections;

public function __construct() {
    $this->connections = new \SplObjectStorage;
}

public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    $this->connections->attach($conn);
}

public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    $this->connections->detach($conn);
}
}
```

This code accepts socket connections and stores them in $connections.

Think that when a client opens a socket they send a hash code to server for identification purpose. So if I have 1000 connections to my server and I want to send some of them a message from another php code that runs seprately. How can I do that. How can I access list of connections? How can I identify who is whom?

Answer (score 0):

I store my open connections in an associative array. I.e. I define a valid name for the connection and thus can access them via primitive array access.

In your case either define the connection or let the client identify itself so you know how you are addressing.

```
    $this->connections = [];

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn { 
        $conn->once('message',function(MessageInterface $msg) use ($conn) {
            $this->connections[$msg] = $conn;
        });
 });
```

(Untested and written from my mobile, sry for that)

Later you can access them the same way

```
$conn = $this->connections[$clientId];
```